# Retrieve(deserialize) a specific property from a json object to a C# struct (json deserialization)

Tags: c#, json

I am attempting to get ONLY the FIRST property (params) from the JSON object below and store it as a struct in C#. I was using the solution on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28098322/parsing-huge-json-files-having-multiple-json-objects-using-json-net?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) page. But I was not successful. If anyone could help or point me in the right direction it would be very helpful. Thank you.

```
{
"params" : [
    {"OneInstance" : "true"},
    {"Single" : "3"},
    {"File_Name" : "test.exe"},
    {"Conf_Name" : "inst.bin"}
],
"directories" : [
    {"file1": "C:/Program Files (x86)/whatever/example"},
    {"file2": "C:/Program Files/another/example"}
]}
```

---

```
public static JValuesStruct paramValues;
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(@"Sample.json");
        using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
                {
                    // Load each object from the stream and do something with it

                    JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);

                    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                    paramValues = (JValuesStruct)serializer.Deserialize(new JTokenReader(obj), typeof(JValuesStruct));
                }
            }
        }


public struct JValuesStruct
{
    public bool OneInstance { get; set; }
    public string Single { get; set; }
    public string File_Name { get; set; }
    public string Conf_Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] of your attempt so far.

Comment: Is there an error? it looks like you're missing a variable name for the output of the `Deserialize` call, unless you're naming a property the same name as a struct (bad practice, BTW).

Comment: There is no syntax error when I run this. It just gives a blank output. Also just made a slight change. Before the struct declaration was missing.

Comment: The first json object ? It is only one json object. Do you mean the first property (params)?

Comment: Yes, the first property (params), and preemptive to any future comments, I am new to working with JSON. Obviously I am going to clean this up later, I would never post finished code online publicly. I am just quickly trying to get this to work. Then I will go back and perform cleanup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. It works perfect. First download "newtonsoft.json" from Nuget and add it to your project. Struct `myStruct` is your deserialized json object converted to a struct.

```
public void DeserializeMyJsonObject()
{
    string json;
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("d:\\json.txt"))
    {
        json = r.ReadToEnd();
    }

    var myStruct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourStruct>(json);

}

public struct YourStruct
{
    [JsonProperty("params")]
    public List<Object> KeyAndProperties { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpful! Cheers

Comment: I would but I am still under 15 reputation so it does not let me

Comment: Since its your question you can accept it. You do not need any reputation to do this.